# Data Level Security / Data Access Security in OBIEE 12c

Tags: weblogic12c, obiee

I'm currently exploring to implement Data Level Security in OBIEE 12c ( 12.2.1.4.0 ) .

Scenario I'm Working on : Lets assume I have created 2 users and assigned them Administrator Role . Now I have to Filter out data for users based on the requirements I have . For Example , User 1 can view data related to city -New York and User 2 can view all data related to every city other than New York .

Kindly refer the below Steps I have tried to Implement Data Level Security :

Step 1 : After Completing Data Model , I connected the RPD to Online .

Step 2 : Went to Identity Manager ( Manage -> Identity ) .

Step 3 : Synchronize Application Roles .

Step 4 : Selected the User to which Data Level Security need to be Implemented .

Step 5 : Clicked the " Permission " of the Particular User .

Step 6 : Selected the " Data Filters " Tab and selected the Object .

Challenge I'm Facing : To filter the Data for the User ( Data Filter Column ) / How to write the Expression for Data Filter Column? . If it's the Final Step or much more need to be done ?

These are the Steps I have tried .
If it's not in the way it should be done please mention how it should be done , Much Appreciated.

Thanks in Advance .

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't give them the Administrator Role. Admin is reserved and bypasses many things.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply , Chris .Means a lot . Now I have Changed the User privileges to BI Consumer . The real issue I'm facing is : How can I Filter the data for the Users and Implement Data Level Security ? Could you give an example for Data Filter Expression ? ( Please Refer the Image Attached )

Comment: Before you start securing things start by thinking whether your security setup makes any sense. At the moment your test app role is a member of EVERYTHING. So you anything you attach to it will apply across the board. Don't play with security and especially not inheritance if you haven't first drawn a picture of how things should work and what makes sense.

Comment: Thanks again , Chris . Okay , Let me make it straight . How can we implement Data Access Security in OBIEE 12c ( 12.2.1.4.0 ) especially Data Filtering for the scenario ( Please Refer Question for the Scenario ) ?

Comment: Exactly the way you tried but NOT using Admin and NOT adding random app roles to others in order to mess everything up through inheritance. Think before you implement.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply , Chris . Thanks for pointing out where I went wrong . After removing the Application Role its working fine . Much Appreciated. So , the Application Roles by passes certain things .